# What the benefit of FactoryGirl over Rspec-Mocks in controller and view specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, factory-bot, rspec-mocks

In an outside-in Rails development approach,we start from the views and walk through the models, in this approach we specify and test each part in isolation so that view specs are isolated from controllers and models, controller specs are isolated from views and models, and so on. So in this approach, where FacctoryGirl can fit, and what's the benefits of using it over rspec doubles when specifying controllers and views. I mean since FactoryGirl requires that the Model been instantiated has to exist before using it, and thus should be tested before controllers and views, so it will not be an outside-in approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's not appropriate to use mocks or doubles when doing integration/acceptance/feature (3 names for the same thing, IMO) specs. At the very least you will need actual valid instances of these issues when writing these types of tests. Using factories allows you to let the factory care about what makes a valid instance without having to duplicate that in knowledge throughout your tests.

Even at the unit level there are times when behavior requires a fully valid instance of the subject under test... you [don't want to stub the system under test](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/don-t-stub-the-system-under-test/), so you turn to your factories as a convenient and consistent way to get an instance that meets your requirements.